# You need to add the ability to change the post?

Tags: python, fastapi

You need to add the ability to change the post.
I don't really understand how to do it.
I hope you'll give me a hand
I ended up with something like this, but this is not what I need

```
@app.put("/api/posts/{id}")
def update_posts(id: int, post: UpdatePost):
    for i in range(len(posts)):
        if posts[i].id == id:
            id = posts[i].id
            post = Post(id=id, header=post.header, content=post.content)
            return post
```

```
    from typing import Optional
    
    from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
    from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
    from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
    
    app = FastAPI()
    
    @dataclass
    class Post:
        id: int
        header: str
        content: str
    
    @dataclass
    class CreatePost:
        header: str
        content: str
    
    @dataclass
    class UpdatePost:
        header: str
        content: str
    
    posts: list[Post] = [
        Post(id=1, header="Python", content="some text about Python"),
        Post(id=2, header="JavaScript", content="some text about JavaScript")
    ]
    
    @app.get("/api/posts")
    def get_posts():
        return posts
    
    @app.get("/api/posts/{id}")
    def get_post(id: int):
        for post in posts:
            if post.id == id:
                return post
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404)
    
    @app.post("/api/posts")
    def create_post(post: CreatePost):
        global posts
        id = posts[-1].id + 1
        post = Post(id=id, header=post.header, content=post.content)
        posts.append(post)
        return post
    
    @app.delete("/api/posts/{id}")
    def delete_post(id: int):
        global posts
        for i in range(len(posts)):
            if posts[i].id == id:
                return posts.pop(i)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404)
```

................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: This is phrased like an enhancement request -- did you mean to post this on the dev forum of some API that you're working with?

Comment: no, this is homework, but I have been sitting for quite a long time, and there is little time, so I decided to ask for help

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  There are lots of people here who'd be happy to help, but nobody's going to be able to figure out how to help you on the Nth part of a major project if you just throw a bunch of code at them with no context or explanation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to ask.